# How do I prevent Eclipse from reporting a compiilation error even though there is none?

Tags: eclipse, maven, compilation, compiler-errors, eclipse-juno

I’m using Eclipse Juno, Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Java 6 on Mac 10.9.5.  I have imported a Maven project, and one of my test classes is reporting a compile error in Eclipse, although everything compiles just fine when I run “mvn clean install” on a command line.  I have this file

```
src/test/java/org/mainco/subco/project/service/ProjectOrganizationServiceTest.java
```

and the beginning of the file has

```
package org.mainco.subco.project.service;

… imports …

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ProjectOrganizationServiceTest extends AbstractNTsubcoTests
{
```

but on the “package org.mainco.subco.project.service” line, Eclipse reports a compilation error, ‘The declared package "org.mainco.subco.project.service" does not match the expected package "org.mainco.subco.service”’.  How do I make it stop reporting this false compilation problem?  I have tried running “mvn eclipse:eclipse” from the project root and restarting Eclipse, but the compilation error remains.

Comment: Is there anything in the folder `org/mainco/subco/service` under either `src/test` or `src/main`?

Comment: Have you tried `Project->Clean...`?